# Second Level Menu

Tags: menus, template-tags

I'm trying to figure out how to do, Second Level Menu as a template function, that persistent when visiting any level, whether its a top level page, or a grand children Page. Any Ideas?

Comment: is that for pages only? i.e. could the menu be made with wp_list_pages()?

Comment: Yeah..it'll be fore pages...i'll have to look into that function, never used it before...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

example:

```
<?php //get top level page ID;
$top = ( $post->post_parent ) ? array_pop(get_post_ancestors($post->ID)) : $post->ID;  
  echo '<ul>'; 
    wp_list_pages('title_li=&child_of='.$top.'&depth=1'); 
  echo '</ul>'; 
?>
```